# Thinkpad W520 DisplayPort/HDMI sound

Tags: nvidia, sound, kde, hdmi, displayport

On my Thinkpad w520 with Nvidia Optimus (using Nvidia properietary drivers) I connected an external monitor via DisplayPort, using a Displayport -> HDMI adapter cable. The monitor has integrated speakers and the first time I did this, sound output worked like a charm

The next day I tried this (powerd up my laptop, hooked it up just like the day before) it stopped working.

Using Kubuntu 14.10.

This is what I see in the audio settings config dialog:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGcXD.png

I tried selecting each one of the High Definition Audio Controllers one by one, but none of them seems willing to output any sound when I press the "Test" button.

Using Alsamixer I selected the Nvidia HDA Sound device and this is what I see instead of volume sliders:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRfOl.png

I also tried switching from the GStreamer Phonon Backed to VLC but that didn't work either.

Any ideas as to anything else I could try are appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, solved it.

After installing pavucontrol

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

the list of *output devices* showed me that my current HDMI output device was **unplugged**.

Switching to the *Configuration* tab in pavucontrol allowed me to select the only *digital output device* that the system said was **plugged in**.

After selecting that one, everything worked like a charm.