# Audio over Displayport on docked Thinkpad T530

Tags: nvidia, sound, displayport

I have Lenovo Thinkpad T530, with docking station. Then I have a monitor (Lenovo ThinkVision Pro2840m), and I have Displayport cable from docking station to the display.

Monitor does have speakers, and I have verified they work under Windows 7.

Under Ubuntu Mate, they are not detected: Preferences -> Hardware -> Sound only shows the internal stereo output of the laptop (which also works), and also `aplay -l` only shows that. [This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/643447/thinkpad-w520-displayport-hdmi-sound) seems to be related, but there the device is detected automatically. I suspect this has something to do with the dock.

I am using NVIDIA binary driver 346.59 for display, under plain up-to-date Ubuntu Mate 15.04, current kernel version 3.19.0-25-generic.

How do I get the DisplayPort sound to work? Or how do I investigate the issue?